# Is it possible to "get" vmin/vmax from axes after using imshow()?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried hunting for this in the matplotlib docs and source and couldn't find an answer:

**Question:**

Is it possible to "get" the arguments used (passed in when created) for `vmin` and `vmax` from an `Axes`, or `AxesImage` object?  (After it is created via `ax.imshow()`)

So something akin to `ax.get_vminmax()`?

**Scenario:**

I want to display a 16-bit grey-scale numpy array with specified vmin/vmax. So no problem, just need to specify vmin/vmax with `imshow()`.

But I also want to put an overlay on that image later (using `ax.text()`) that will display the vmin/vmax values in the overlay.

I'd like to use a generic function to do that, *that doesn't need the previously specified vmin/vmax remembered and also passed into my "annotate" function*, but instead can just be passed an Axes, and then "get" the vmin/vmax by querying the Axes object.

*This is just out of code nicety and not having to add bunches of args to different functions as opposed to just being able to query the passed in objects themselves,*

thanks!
Richard

Comment: You get it from the scalar mappable or its norm.  The axes doesn't know about it, because an axes can have may objects drawn on it.

Comment: thanks!
So if i've got an axes already, then the right way to get at this is for each "image" in axes, then use get_clim()?

for a in ax.get_images():
    print('here is vmin/max:', a.get_clim())

Comment: Sure, or just keep track of the images as you make them.

Comment: Cool - thanks Jody!

Comment: @Richard You should write this up as an answer for future visitors - was very helpful for me!

Comment: Done! ...answer below

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is to first realize (I didn't) that each `axes` can have multiple images in it - so what you need to do is get the vmin/vmax for each image within the `axes`.

...though typically I guess, like me, most people only have a single image in each axes.

Here is a code snippet, if `ax` is a variable for your axes and you're only wanting the vmin/vmax for the first image:

```
imgs = ax.get_images()
if len(imgs) > 0:
   vmin, vmax = imgs[0].get_clim()
```